# python shell , cannot see what I type

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, terminal, pdb

I'm working with python flask in a Lubuntu VM (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
) running on windows 10.

When running the server and debugging with pdb, sometimes I can't see what I type although the commands are received and executed.

I usually need to stop the server and restart it again which is quite inconvenient. Did anyone find and sort this issue before?

I've used terminator and LXTerminal, but both show the same behaviour

Thanks in advance.